# docker stack deploy from compose file - all services one node?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I have a docker-compose file with 10 services (containers).  I have it configured one instance of each server.

When I execute the stack deploy, all 10 services go to one node (manager).

I trust that adding a second instance of a service will distribute it, but I want my 10 unique services distributed.

Comment: Share compose file please, are you using a private registry?

Comment: Yes, private registry.

Comment: what are you looking for in compose file?  There is a bit of private IP in it...

Comment: The compose file has nothing swarm specific in it

Comment: Make sure there are no constraints like node role == manager .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a private registry its important to share the login and credentials with the worker nodes by using

```
docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the reputation to comment but...

If you are using a private registry that requires a ca certificate `--with-registry-auth` alone doesn't seem to work. You need to install the ca certificate to each node.

We are using Harbor but I guess that's not that relevant.

In my case I had to do something like:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/10.10.1.5
sudo cp ca.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/10.10.1.5/.
```

It's really quite obvious but I spent quite some time on this and decided to share.