# Number of replicas in swarm doesn't start in worker node (1/4)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, swarm

I started a flask API service onto docker swarm cluster with 1 master and 3 worker node. I have deployed task using the following docker compose file,

```
version: '3'

services:
  xgboost-model-api:
image: xgboost-model-api
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
deploy:
  mode: global
networks:
  - xgboost-net

networks:
   xgboost-net:
```

I deployed the task using the following docker swarm command,

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml xgboost-swarm
```

However, the task was started only on my master node and not on any worker node.

```
$ docker service ls
ID            NAME                             MODE        REPLICAS  IMAGE
pgd8cktr4foz  viz                              replicated  1/1       
dockersamples/visualizer
twrpr4av4c7f  xgboost-swarm_xgboost-model-api  global      1/4       xgboost-model-api
xxrfn1w7eqw6  dockercloud-server-proxy         global      1/1       dockercloud/server-proxy
```

Dockerfile being used is [here](https://github.com/shabazbpatel/xgboost-model-api/blob/master/Dockerfile). Any thoughts on why this behavior occurs would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker stack deploy from compose file - all services one node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46242133/docker-stack-deploy-from-compose-file-all-services-one-node)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46242133/docker-stack-deploy-from-compose-file-all-services-one-node/46243004#46243004) (duplicate?):

If you are using a private registry its important to share the login and credentials with the worker nodes by using

> docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth

---- UPDATE

From your compose file it doesn't look like you are using a private registry. Generally speaking if containers can't start successfuly on the workers they will end up on the manager. 
Some possible reasons for this are:

1. Can't access private registry (fix with --with-registry-auth)
2. Application requires some change on the host to run (like elasticSearch requires vm.max_map_count=262144)
3. HealthCheck fails on other node because of poorly written helthcheck
4. Network setting issues preventing pulling an image

Try removing your stack and running it again. Then do `docker service ps --no-trunc {serviceName}` this might show you tasks that should run the service on another node and why it failed.

Check out [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372848/docker-swarm-how-to-find-out-why-service-cant-start) for more troubleshooting tips.